# How to search document using ObjectId in MongoDB (Anypoint Studio)

Tags: mongodb, mule, anypoint-studio

I'm using AnypointStudio to create an API and I'm trying to search for a document using the ObjectId on MongoDB but I can't make it work. I have tried searching with the use of other fields in the collection and it works just fine. Here is the value of the `Find query` I am currently using.

```
output application/json
---
{   
    "_id" : "5c088f4264c73358f4f7e3c0"
}
```

Here's an example result I have upon searching with the use of the `uid` field.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c088f4264c73357f4f7e3c0"
    },
    "uid": "test",
    "name": "test",
    "validUser": true,
    "oauth_client_id": "55628a5730ad44719e63b34c36604401",
    "customer": "test customer"
}
```

Can anyone please help me to search document using the `ObjectId`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the answer with some experimentations. I noticed the structure of the `_id` field and tried using this in the query `"_id" : {"$oid" : "5c088f4264c73358f4f7e3c0"}` but won't work since `$` symbol is a reference symbol(?). So I tried using `\` before the `$` and it works.

```
output application/json
---
{
    "_id" : {"\$oid" : "5c088f4264c73358f4f7e3c0"}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The example you show should work, you may need to wrap it like this

```
{   
    _id : ObjectId("5c088f4264c73358f4f7e3c0") 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried this one but I got `Unable to resolve reference of ObjectId.` error in the Find Query textbox.